# How to set up Excel VBA Loop for vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a dashboard (image below) where I manually add entries. Then there is a log (image below) where all entries are recorded with the help of `IF` and `Vlookup` functions.

I need a code so so that every output cell in the log finds through all the entries in the dashboard and gives the answer. I think  loop for `vlookup` will be used.

[image]

[Edit]
Consider the Dasboard table as a discrete table where manually entries are posted.
Consider log table as a continues table where record of every hour for each date is kept. The entries from Dashboard table get posted to the log table. New Image attached   [New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHvgc.png)

I have entered this function in output column in the log table:

> ```
>  =IF( AND(H3=$B$3,I3>= $C$3,I3<$D$3) ,$E$3,0)  + IF(AND(H3=$B$4,I3>= 
>  $C$4,I3<$D$4) ,$E$4,0) + IF (AND(H3=$B$5,I3>= $C$5,I3<$D$5), $E$5,0)
> ```

This works fine for me for plotting the entries but the problem is for every row in the dashboard i have to add a new IF-And function in the above. so for example if i want to add the 4th row of dashboard to be sync with the log ill have to add

> ```
> +If(AND(H3=$B$6,I3>=$C$6,I3<$D$6),$E$6,0)
> ```

I want  every row in the dashboard to add automatically somehow with a loop like:
i = variable

> ```
> = If (AND(H3=$B$i,I3>= $C$i,I3<$D$i), $E$i,0)
> ```

Only one i will be greater than 0 while the rest will be zero. so the function should return me the sum of all i rather than just the last iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading How to Ask might help you to improve your question. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Potentially useful references: [`WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) or [`WorksheetFunction.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just filldown the formula manually? if insist with macro, something like

```
Sub test()
Range("K3").Value = "X"
Range("K3:K10").FillDown
End Sub
```

replace "X" with your formula, keep the " "
replace K10 with how far down you want

----edit----

let me break down below for you,

1. match(H3,B:B,0), will find the correct row in B that = H, in H3 case it finds B3
2. INDEX(B:E,**MATCH(H3,B:B,0)**,2) -> now it find B3, index let you find C3 (notice the 2,3,4 in later codes, it means the column from B3)
3. and (I3>=...,J3>=...)now we got both start and end time, we use I and J to compare
4. if 3. is true, lookup the output column, else 0

> =IF(AND(I3>=INDEX(B:E,MATCH(H3,B:B,0),2),J3>=INDEX(B:E,MATCH(H3,B:B,0),3)),INDEX(B:E,MATCH(H3,B:B,0),4),0)

Comment: What should i define X for?

Comment: i am using this formula =IF(AND(H3=$B$3,I3>=$C$3,J3<=$D$3),VLOOKUP(H3,$B$3:$E$8,4,FALSE)) in output column in the log. If i drag it down manually the formula wont check the every entry in the dashboard. To check every entry i have to manually write the formula for every entry. This is ok in 4 entries or less but if there are 10 or more entries it is not possible to write that long formula.

Comment: ok, got your issue, you will need to find the correct row to reference in your first part, this make it more complicate, will amend the code

Comment: Thanks Osman i got you. But there is one problem with this. What if there are more entries for one date? For example for date 22-11-18 there are two entries with different times. The formula you suggested will only take into account the first entry.

Comment: how do you decide which entries to take in that case?

Comment: Both entries have to be taken as they have different hours. I want to do the tracking hour wise.

Comment: sorry i don't really get your meaning, do you mean if you got 22 10am and 22 11am, you want to input 22 11am and get it to match with the 2nd figure?